# Pandas Column operation with dates

Tags: python, date, pandas

I have a dataframe, mainly with dates. Here is what I want to do

From the old date variable(DTDate), I want to create a new date variable, if the old date is Monday, the new date will be same, but if the old date is any date other than Monday, the new date will give me the date of the next Monday. So finally all the items in new date will be only with Monday.

I have been trying with a function and apply. here is my data set and code

```
    Date call   DTDate      weekday     weekdayNo
0   31/12/2014  2014-12-31  Wednesday   3
1   29/10/2014  2014-10-29  Wednesday   3
2   28/10/2014  2014-10-28  Tuesday     2
3   27/3/2015   2015-03-27  Friday      5
4   27/2/2015   2015-02-27  Friday      5
5   27/11/2014  2014-11-27  Thursday    4
6   27/10/2014  2014-10-27  Monday      1
7   26/3/2015   2015-03-26  Thursday    4
8   26/2/2015   2015-02-26  Thursday    4
9   26/12/2014  2014-12-26  Friday      5
10  26/11/2014  2014-11-26  Wednesday   3
11  26/10/2014  2014-10-26  Sunday      0
12  25/3/2015   2015-03-25  Wednesday   3
13  25/12/2014  2014-12-25  Thursday    4
14  24/3/2015   2015-03-24  Tuesday     2
15  24/2/2015   2015-02-24  Tuesday     2
16  24/12/2014  2014-12-24  Wednesday   3
17  24/11/2014  2014-11-24  Monday      1
18  23/3/2015   2015-03-23  Monday      1
```

The code is

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

def AddDate(row):
    if row['weekdayNo']==0:
        return row['DTDate'] + timedelta(days=1)
    elif row['weekdayNo'] ==2:
        return row['DTDate'] + timedelta(days=6)
    elif row['weekdayNo'] ==3:
       return row['DTDate'] + timedelta(days=5)
    elif row['weekdayNo'] ==4:
       return row['DTDate'] + timedelta(days=4)
    elif row['weekdayNo'] ==5:
       return row['DTDate'] + timedelta(days=3) 
    elif row['weekdayNo'] ==6:
       return row['DTDate'] + timedelta(days=2)
    else:
       return row['DTDate']

 DF['newDate'] = DF.apply(AddDate, axis=1)
```

and I am getting the following, it is the exact same thing, nothing changed

```
     Date call  DTDate       weekday    weekdayNo   newDate
 0  31/12/2014  2014-12-31  Wednesday      3        2014-12-31
 1  29/10/2014  2014-10-29  Wednesday      3        2014-10-29
 2  28/10/2014  2014-10-28  Tuesday        2        2014-10-28
 3  27/3/2015   2015-03-27  Friday         5        2015-03-27
 4  27/2/2015   2015-02-27  Friday         5        2015-02-27
 5  27/11/2014  2014-11-27  Thursday       4        2014-11-27
 6  27/10/2014  2014-10-27  Monday         1        2014-10-27
 7  26/3/2015   2015-03-26  Thursday       4        2015-03-26
 8  26/2/2015   2015-02-26  Thursday       4        2015-02-26
 9  26/12/2014  2014-12-26  Friday         5        2014-12-26
 10 26/11/2014  2014-11-26  Wednesday      3        2014-11-26
 11 26/10/2014  2014-10-26  Sunday         0        2014-10-26
 12 25/3/2015   2015-03-25  Wednesday      3        2015-03-25
 13 25/12/2014  2014-12-25  Thursday       4        2014-12-25
 14 24/3/2015   2015-03-24  Tuesday        2        2015-03-24
 15 24/2/2015   2015-02-24  Tuesday        2        2015-02-24
 16 24/12/2014  2014-12-24  Wednesday      3        2014-12-24
 17 24/11/2014  2014-11-24  Monday         1        2014-11-24
 18 23/3/2015   2015-03-23  Monday         1        2015-03-23
```

I also think, this idea is not good, if there is something better, Please would anyone like to suggest, what that might be?? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `DF.DTDate` of dtype `datetime`? Can you try after converting it to a datetime`df.DTDate = pd.to_datetime(DF.DTDate)`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AddDate` function can be made simpler, infact a single liner

```
In [34]: df['newDate'] = df['DTDate'].apply(lambda x: x + timedelta(days=7-x.dayofweek)
                                            if x.dayofweek else x)
```

Here, the lambda function  `lambda x: x + timedelta(days=7-x.dayofweek) if x.dayofweek else x` 
 adds delta=`7-x.dayofweek` days if it's not a Monday.

To validate new `weekday` lets create a new column `newdayofweek`

```
In [35]: df['newdayofweek'] = df['newDate'].apply(lambda x: x.dayofweek)

In [36]: df
Out[36]:
    Date        call     DTDate    weekday  weekdayNo    newDate  newdayofweek
0      0  31/12/2014 2014-12-31  Wednesday          3 2015-01-05             0
1      1  29/10/2014 2014-10-29  Wednesday          3 2014-11-03             0
2      2  28/10/2014 2014-10-28    Tuesday          2 2014-11-03             0
3      3   27/3/2015 2015-03-27     Friday          5 2015-03-30             0
4      4   27/2/2015 2015-02-27     Friday          5 2015-03-02             0
5      5  27/11/2014 2014-11-27   Thursday          4 2014-12-01             0
6      6  27/10/2014 2014-10-27     Monday          1 2014-10-27             0
7      7   26/3/2015 2015-03-26   Thursday          4 2015-03-30             0
8      8   26/2/2015 2015-02-26   Thursday          4 2015-03-02             0
9      9  26/12/2014 2014-12-26     Friday          5 2014-12-29             0
10    10  26/11/2014 2014-11-26  Wednesday          3 2014-12-01             0
11    11  26/10/2014 2014-10-26     Sunday          0 2014-10-27             0
12    12   25/3/2015 2015-03-25  Wednesday          3 2015-03-30             0
13    13  25/12/2014 2014-12-25   Thursday          4 2014-12-29             0
14    14   24/3/2015 2015-03-24    Tuesday          2 2015-03-30             0
15    15   24/2/2015 2015-02-24    Tuesday          2 2015-03-02             0
16    16  24/12/2014 2014-12-24  Wednesday          3 2014-12-29             0
17    17  24/11/2014 2014-11-24     Monday          1 2014-11-24             0
18    18   23/3/2015 2015-03-23     Monday          1 2015-03-23             0
```

Note: The day of the week with Monday=0, Sunday=6

Comment: Thanks mate, brilliant solution, but for some reasons I am getting an error...`'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'dayofweek'` any suggestion?? sorry my previous comment was wrong

Comment: Is your `type(df['DTDate'][0]) == pandas.tslib.Timestamp`? If not then convert it `df['DTDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DTDate'])`

Comment: ok..now it worked.....excellent ....thanks a lot , thank you so much? can you just suggest something to read about the problem `to_datetime`, or when do I need it??it would be great, thanks a lot...or if you have some time, can you explain in some words, maybe??

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to `import datetime` or `timedelta` to do this.

```
df['DTDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DTDate'])  # can skip this if column 'DTDate' is already of the right type
```

`x.weekday()` extracts the day of the week with Monday=0 and Sunday=6.

```
df['newDate'] = df.DTDate.apply(lambda x: x + pd.DateOffset(days=7-x.weekday()) if  x.weekday() else x)
```

yields:

```
    Date_call     DTDate    weekday  weekdayNo    newDate
0  2014-12-31 2014-12-31  Wednesday          3 2015-01-05
1  2014-10-29 2014-10-29  Wednesday          3 2014-11-03
2  2014-10-28 2014-10-28    Tuesday          2 2014-11-03
3  2015-03-27 2015-03-27     Friday          5 2015-03-30
4  2015-02-27 2015-02-27     Friday          5 2015-03-02
5  2014-11-27 2014-11-27   Thursday          4 2014-12-01
6  2014-10-27 2014-10-27     Monday          1 2014-10-27
7  2015-03-26 2015-03-26   Thursday          4 2015-03-30
8  2015-02-26 2015-02-26   Thursday          4 2015-03-02
9  2014-12-26 2014-12-26     Friday          5 2014-12-29
10 2014-11-26 2014-11-26  Wednesday          3 2014-12-01
11 2014-10-26 2014-10-26     Sunday          0 2014-10-27
12 2015-03-25 2015-03-25  Wednesday          3 2015-03-30
13 2014-12-25 2014-12-25   Thursday          4 2014-12-29
14 2015-03-24 2015-03-24    Tuesday          2 2015-03-30
15 2015-02-24 2015-02-24    Tuesday          2 2015-03-02
16 2014-12-24 2014-12-24  Wednesday          3 2014-12-29
17 2014-11-24 2014-11-24     Monday          1 2014-11-24
18 2015-03-23 2015-03-23     Monday          1 2015-03-23
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much more performant way of doing this.

```
In [50]: s = Series(pd.date_range('20000101',freq='D',periods=10000))

In [51]: result = s.where(s.dt.weekday==0,pd.TimedeltaIndex(7-s.dt.weekday,unit='d')+s)

In [52]: expected = s.apply(lambda x: x + pd.DateOffset(days=7-x.weekday()) if  x.weekday() else x)

In [53]: (result==expected).all()
Out[53]: True
```

This is essentially looping in python space.

```
In [54]: %timeit s.apply(lambda x: x + pd.DateOffset(days=7-x.weekday()) if  x.weekday() else x)
1 loops, best of 3: 244 ms per loop
```

Here we are constructing a TimedeltaIndex of the days to add. The `.where` is an equivalent idiom to the `if-then`, but this is a vectorized expression.

```
In [55]: %timeit s.where(s.dt.weekday==0,pd.TimedeltaIndex(7-s.dt.weekday,unit='d')+s)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.69 ms per loop
```